# ¿Porque no imprime la matriz sin senos y cosenos en jupyter notebooks?

Tags: python, jupyter, sympy

Estoy apenas usando la librería sympy y al momento de hacer una multiplicación de matrices jupyter notebook imprime los senos y cosenos como si no los hubiera sustituido anteriormente.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

ya intente colocarlo de las siguientes formas:

```
Afinal = A1*A2*A3
Afinal
```

o con sólo hacer la multiplicación, pero sigue sin funcionar

```
A1*A2*A3
```

Adjuntare el codigo.

```
from sympy import * 
init_printing(fontsize='5pt')

theta_i=Symbol("theta_1")
alpha_i1=Symbol("alpha_1")
a_i1=Symbol("a_1")
d_i=Symbol("d_1")

T = Matrix([[cos(theta_i), -sin(theta_i)*cos(alpha_i1), 
sin(theta_i)*sin(alpha_i1), cos(theta_i)*a_i1],
[sin(theta_i), cos(theta_i)*cos(alpha_i1), -cos(theta_i)*sin(alpha_i1), 
sin(theta_i)*a_i1],
[0, sin(alpha_i1), cos(alpha_i1), d_i],
[0,0,0,1]])
display(T)


A1 = T
A2 = T
A3 = T
A1.subs(a_i1,0).subs(d_i,"d_1").subs(alpha_i1,-pi/2).subs(theta_i,0)
A2.subs(a_i1,0).subs(d_i,"d_2").subs(alpha_i1,-pi/2).subs(theta_i,-pi/2)
A3.subs(a_i1,0).subs(d_i,"d_3").subs(alpha_i1,0).subs(theta_i,0)
Afinal = A1*A2*A3
display(Afinal)
```

Answer (score 1):

Bueno el problema era que no almacenaba el resultado al momento de cambiar valores con .subs
`A2 = A2.subs(a_i1,0).subs(d_i,"d_2").subs(alpha_i1,-pi/2).subs(theta_i,-pi/2)`